# How to cascade events to newly created objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am missing something obvious:)

I have a class, *this*, that creates objects of another class, *svm*. I wish to trigger the OnSaved method in the created object when the creator receives a saved event. (I hope that's clear).

But the Saved event in this object always remains null. The method of svm.OnSaved is never added to it.

```
            foreach (var rx in rxs)
            {
                StringByColumnViewModel svm = new StringByColumnViewModel();

                this.Saved +=  svm.OnSaved;
            }
```

this.Saved is:

```
    public event EventHandler Saved;       
    protected virtual void OnSaved()
    {
        if (Saved != null)
        {
            Saved(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

and svm.OnSaved is:

```
public class StringByColumnViewModel 
{
    public EventHandler OnSaved;

    public StringByColumnViewModel() 
    {
        this.OnSaved = (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Here I am"); };
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Addendum: In the parent class, the Saved event is triggered as:

```
    private DelegateCommand save;
    public DelegateCommand Save
    {
        get
        {
            if (save == null)
            {
                save = new DelegateCommand(
                    () => this.doSave()
                    );
            }
            return save;
        }
    }
    private object doSave()
    {
        OnSaved();    <--THE SAVED EVENT IS NULL???
        return null;
    }
```

Addendum 2: Believing that the problem is that the top-class is not reaching the "creator" class, how is this done?

The view model of the top class does:

```
        ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel = new MyNewViewModel();
```

This fails:

```
        this.Saved += CurrentViewModel.OnSaved();
```

when ViewModelBase has:

```
        public event EventHandler Saved;
        public EventHandler OnSaved()    
        {
            if (Saved != null)
            {
                Saved(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
```

with "not all code paths return a value"

What to do??

Comment: put a breakpoint on `this.Saved +=  svm.OnSaved;` and make sure it is called before `OnSaved()`.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Hi. I did. It is. ???

Comment: and when you step through that line with F10, you should see that this.Saved is not null.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez It remains null.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Ooops. I am wrong. It is NOT null, but when OnSaved is used, the "Saved" in the OnSaved() method IS null.

Comment: then either you're calling Saved _before_ or you are unsubscribing before OnSaved (e.g. `this.Saved -= svm.OnSaved;`... or `this.Saved = null;`)

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Does it matter that the event this.Saved is being defined in a parent base clase of which "this" is a child of?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. The derived class just inherits the event from its base class.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez F10 shows it not to be null, but it is null when OnSaved is called??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61220/discussion-between-alan-wayne-and-eren-ersonmez).

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I've added the triggering code. At time of trigger, the event shows null ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you actually call

```
        foreach (var rx in rxs)
        {
            StringByColumnViewModel svm = new StringByColumnViewModel();

            this.Saved +=  svm.OnSaved;
        }
```

to subscribe before event raised? And you not unsubscribe event after that? maybe you declared event with the same name in derived class, that hides event in base class. Could you post more of your code?

Here is simple working example, where creator call svm.OnSaved

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var th = new This();
        th.OnSaved(); //creator receives a saved event
    }
}

public class This
{
    public event EventHandler Saved;
    public virtual void OnSaved()//made public in that example
    {
        if (Saved != null)
        {
            Saved(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public This()
    {
        var rxs = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        foreach (var rx in rxs)
        {
            var svm = new StringByColumnViewModel();

            this.Saved += svm.OnSaved;
        }
    }
}

public class StringByColumnViewModel
{
    public EventHandler OnSaved;

    public StringByColumnViewModel()
    {
        this.OnSaved = (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Here I am"); };
    }
}
```

try not use delegates instead of events, change StringByColumnViewModel to

```
public class StringByColumnViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler OnSaved;

    public StringByColumnViewModel()
    {
        this.OnSaved = (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Here I am"); };
    }

    public void RaiseSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = OnSaved;
        if (handler!= null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
 this.Saved += svm.RaiseSave;
```

Comment: Except for the opening th.Onsaved(), I copied your code exactly. I'm still getting null--even when changing the name on the event (just to avoid any name conflicts) ?? There must be something with inheritance (by the way, I'm using visual studio 2010 if it matters).

Comment: I think I found the problem...but I don't know how to fix it. The problem is my creator class is itself created by a top class. The trigger for "Saved" resides in the TOP class. Hence, the top class never had events added. So how (in MVVM) do I have the topmost class call the event in the creator? Your help is really appreciated! The creator was made with a ContentPresenter.

Comment: Top class is your viewmodel, which contains DelegateCommand Save(your trigger for save) and instance of Creator, is that right? If so you have to change       
                save = new DelegateCommand(
                    () => this.doSave()
                    );
on

                save = new DelegateCommand(
                    () => CreatorInstance.OnSaved()
                    );
//probably need to add public method with right name with logic like in OnSaved

Comment: Please see my last addendum. How do you correctly add an event from the topclass to the "creator" class? Thanks much!

Comment: i don't have enough reputation so can answer only here
with "not all code paths return a value"
What to do??
Change signature of method, return type must be void
aka      
public void OnSaved()    
        {
            if (Saved != null)
            {
                Saved(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

Comment: where is "here"?? Ooops just saw it. Thanks

Comment: only in comments of my answer

Comment: now get "No overload for 'OnSaved' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'"  ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61228/discussion-between-roman-g-and-alan-wayne).

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that important information to help you find the error is missing but based on the fact that

- You assign an event handler (and have verified that)
- That the event handler is null on the object where you call OnSaved
- That you in your text calls *this* a class

It might be that you are confusing classes and objects. The event handler is assigned to a specific object and only that one object and you might be calling OnSaved on a different object which doesn't have an event handler boud to said event

The resolution to that would be to make sure that you are using the right instance of the class Ie the right object. If you expect it to be the same object